# Error: Unable to initialize main class org.testng.TestNG

Tags: testng

I am using TestNG testng-6.14.3.jar, I downloaded it and placed in test folder where testng.xml resides,

when I give the command

```
java -cp "/c/Project/Test/Dependency/testng-6.14.3.jar" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

it gives Error:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor="New Oracle"
Error: Unable to initialize main class org.testng.TestNG
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException
```

I am running this operation on windows via GitBash,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you observe the exception  com/beust/jcommander/ParameterException its looking for ParameterException class in com/beust/jcommander package which is available in jcommander.jar file

See all depends jars here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng/6.14.3 add supporting jars to avoid this issue.

Comment: Hi added it to maven and still i am getting this error